# MySQL create trigger for logging table

Tags: mysql, triggers

Hello I am new for MySQL. I have 2 table, a data table and a log/history table. I would like to make a trigger, that put the old data from `Data` to `Data_log` if any of the column change on the `Data`. I made a trigger but I don't know how to check if the value of any column changes. Lately I would like to create some procedure/view which can return one line data on a specific date. Like return all field from ID 1 on 2022-03-27

Data:

| ID | name | data | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | thing1 | desc of t1 | 100 |
| 2 | thing2 | desc of t2 | 300 |

Data_log:

| log_id | data_id | column_name | old_data | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | data | desc t1 | 2022-03-28 06:49:14 |
| 2 | 2 | price | 600 | 2022-03-28 11:34:46 |
| 3 | 1 | price | 4400 | 2022-03-28 09:15:54 |

Trigger (only check price column):

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `log_old_data` BEFORE UPDATE ON `data`
    INSERT INTO data_log
    (
        data_id,
        old_data 
    )
    VALUES
    (
      OLD.id,
      OLD.price <- I need here a Select I think
    );
END//
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have few columns, it may be simpler to do it "by hand" for every columns

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `log_old_data` BEFORE UPDATE ON `data`
    IF NEW.name != OLD.name THEN
        INSERT INTO data_log (data_id, old_data) VALUES (OLD.id, OLD.name);
    END IF;

    IF NEW.data != OLD.data THEN
        INSERT INTO data_log (data_id, old_data) VALUES (OLD.id, OLD.data);
    END IF;

    IF NEW.price != OLD.price THEN
        INSERT INTO data_log (data_id, old_data) VALUES (OLD.id, OLD.price);
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

PS: I did not test it, but it should work. If it doesn't, leave your mysql version to allow me to test on your version

---

For the `SELECT` part, since yo record every change on a separate table you only have to do a query on it

```sql
SELECT * FROM log_old_data WHERE `log_id` = 1 AND DATE(`date`) = '2022-03-27';
```

PS: Careful, `DATE()` on a `WHERE` condition may not be the perfect choice, it will not use indexes. I use generated columns to add index on date for this kind of case.

Comment: Okay I'll try it. Later I have to do this, with more columns.